# OrmLiteConfigUtil NoClassDefFoundError in android intellij project

Tags: android, intellij-idea, ormlite

When running OrmLiteConfigUtil for creating the table config text file, a NoClassDefFoundError   for com/j256/ormlite/android/apptools/OrmLiteConfigUtil is thrown although the libs are properly added to the project dependencies.

Libs have a "Provided" scope and contain ormlite-core and ormlite-android.

Comment: Provide the Stacktrace/logcat along with corresponding code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved !
The libs actually needed the "Compiled" scope for running OrmLiteConfigUtil under Intellij.
If they are "Provided", this simply does not work !

The Stacktrace gave:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/j256/ormlite/android/apptools/OrmLiteConfigUtil
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:116)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteConfigUtil
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 15 more

    Process finished with exit code 1
```